# Grabbing links from google maps popup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab the links from the embedded google map in the **Supply Chain Map** on [here](https://www.musimmas.com/sustainability/traceability/) to scrape the table at the links in the pop-ups but am struggling to find them. Does anyone know an easy way to pull these links from that page?

Example of those links from the popups are:

- https://www.musimmas.com/report/mikie-oleo-nabati-industri-bekasi-west-java-july-september-2020/
- https://www.musimmas.com/report/mikie-oleo-nabati-industri-bekasi-west-java-april-june-2020/

I would like to then use bs4 to convert the tables at those links into a `pandas` `dataframe` and export them to a `csv` file.

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question. What exactly do you want to scrape? you have provided multiple links. From the links you want to scrape `Location`, `Address..`?

Comment: Those multiple links appear in the popups in the map in the Supply Chain Map here - https://www.musimmas.com/sustainability/traceability/ So I want to first scrape those links and then the tables that are in those links. But my problem right now is now first trying to get those links from that embedded google map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded in JSON format via sending a `GET` request to

```
https://www.musimmas.com/presence/icof/
```

You can extract the data with just the `requests` module, there's no need for `BeautifulSoup`

```
import requests


headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
    "referer": "https://www.musimmas.com/sustainability/traceability/",
}

response = requests.get(
    "https://www.musimmas.com/presence/icof/", headers=headers,
).json()

# To get all links try the following
for data in response:
    if data["reports"]:
        reports = data["reports"]
        for links in reports:
            print(links["link"])
        print("-" * 20)
```

Partial output:

```
https://www.musimmas.com/report/musim-mastika-oils-fats-johor-malaysia-july-september-2020/
/report/musim-mastika-oils-fats-johor-malaysia-april-june-2020/
/report/musim-mastika-oil-fats-johor-malaysia-january-march-2020/
/report/musim-mastika-oil-fats-johor-malaysia-october-december-2019/
/report/musim-mastika-oil-fats-johor-malaysia-july-september-2019/
--------------------
https://www.musimmas.com/report/musim-mas-pelalawan-riau-july-september-2020/
/report/musim-mas-pelalawan-riau-april-june-2020/
/report/musim-mas-pelalawan-riau-january-march-2020/
/report/musim-mas-pelalawan-riau-october-december-2019/
/report/musim-mas-pelalawan-riau-july-september-2019/
/supply-chain-map/summary-report/musim-mas-pelalawan-riau/period-april-june-2019.html
--------------------
```